# Doc to tiff file using VB is copying content in black and white

Tags: vb.net, vba, tiff, doc

I've written below code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim objWdDoc As Word.Document
        Dim objWord As Word.Application
        Dim sDesktop As String =
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile") & "\Desktop\"

        objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'objWdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(sDesktop & "testdocument.doc")
        objWdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\\test\\Test Doc to tiff\\test docs.doc")
        objWord.Visible = True

        'Select Printer
        objWord.ActivePrinter = ""
        'Print to Tiff
        'objWdDoc.PrintOut(Range:=WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument,
        'OutputFileName:=sDesktop & "test.tiff",
        'Item:=WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent,
        'PrintToFile:=True)
        objWdDoc.PrintOut(Range:=WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument,
                              OutputFileName:="C:\\test\\Test Doc to tiff\\" & "test.tiff",
                              Item:=WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent,
                              PrintToFile:=True)
        'Close Document
        objWdDoc.Close()
        'Close Word
        objWord.Quit()
        'General Cleanup
        objWdDoc = Nothing
        objWord = Nothing
    End Sub

End Module
```

This code is doing a job of converting Word doc to Tiff file (multiple pages). But it's copying the content but in black and white.

I tried different options to change the properties of the print but no luck.

Comment: Just a detail: This is VBA qustion only, not VB.NET. Also sDesktop is unused. As for Black & white, I think there could be only 2 reasons: Printer settings or TIFF settings (color depth). However, since this is VBA, I cannot help, my VBA knowledge got rusty...

Comment: @Oak_3260548 The code above is NOT VBA code it must be VB.NET. VBA requires the SET keyword to assign objects to variables, which this code is not using. VBA also does not use Imports statements.